# Is there any implementation to Remove by Key and get the Value at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, asymptotic-complexity, trygetvalue

I'm doing a performance critical program (little academic stuff) and I'm looking to optimize wherever possible (not like it proved "this is the" bottleneck).

I have a custom dictionary structure (a wrapper around .NET `Dictionary<,>`) and I would constantly Remove items at one stage (by the `Key` value). I need the `Value` of the removed items. Right now I have to do:

```
T t;
if !TryGet(key, out t)
   return false;

Remove(key);
```

That's two lookups. I would love this:

```
public bool Remove(S key, out T value)
{
    // implementation
}
```

I know there is nothing in the framework, but is there an implementation somewhere? If so I would change my backing dictionary with that one.

**Edit:** Hmm I know both `TryGetValue` and `Remove` are O(1). Just knowing if there is any collection structure that would give the same effect in just one lookup. As I said I'm trying to optimize as much as possible. Just knowing.

Comment: Umm, both `Get` and `Remove` in the `Dictionary` have the amortized complexity of `O(1)`, so calling `Get` + `Remove` will still give you `O(1)`...

Comment: Looks like I will have to write one my own..

Comment: Looks that way, there's nothing built-in that would return the removed item from the Dictionary.

Comment: @nawfal Please run a profiler (or do your _own_ profiling) against your application to identify _real_ bottlenecks before rolling your own `Dictionary<,>` implementation. (alternatively, you can grab the [Mono Dictionary<,> implementation from its source code repository...](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs))

Comment: @ChrisSinclair don't worry, if ever I'm writing my own I will get the original source first and build on it. Sure I will time too (that's always on the forefront of my thought)

Comment: Closing the question with duplicate link. The original question has an answer today (.NET Core 2.0 onwards).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [University of Copenehagen's Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) has a `Dictionary.Remove()` method that appears to do what you want:

> bool Remove(K k, out V v)
>
> Returns true if the dictionary contains an entry whose key equals k
>   and if so removes that entry and assigns the associated value to v;
>   otherwise returns false and assigns the default value for T to v.

I've not used this library myself, but I've seen it recommended a few times here on Stack Overflow. It's free to use commercially, subject to [this MIT-style license](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/LICENSE.txt).

Comment: What kind of searching did you do to find that? Thanks :)

Comment: I had an old bookmark from ages ago that I finally remembered about. :)

Comment: I just looked the source, and they do what I want exactly. I mean single lookup

Answer (score 8):

The **[ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129(v=vs.110).aspx)** has a `TryRemove` method that does this. It works just like `TryGet` but it also removes the element.

Answer (score 7):

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) and [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx) methods are both *O(1)* operations, so I don't think you should be concerned about performance here.

Comment: Sorry unfortunately this doesnt answer the question. May be I wasnt clear enough with my requirement.

Comment: I basically agree, but `O(1)` doesn't say anything about the absolute time an operation takes. It just says something about how the execution time develops with a changing number of items. An operation that always takes 10 seconds is `O(1)` but still can be a very real performance problem. So, "O(1) = fast" is not always a legit conclusion. Having said that, optimizing arbitrary things without attaching a profiler first is premature optimization and a bad idea.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Absolutely, that's what I was thinking about (though .NET Dictionary is insanely fast).

Comment: So you'll have to write something on your own (but I don't have an idea how it could be done on `Dictionary`, really). `Dictionary` is that fast, because it uses hashing for finding items within a set. That *O(1)* operation does just that - calculates `HashCode` and check if it's already set.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes, but along with that, before the removal, I can `out` the `Value` back. I mean in a custom dictionary if I have to roll one myself. I'm not taking about the standard dictionary.