# Remove from Dictionary by Key and Retrieve Value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Is there a way to remove an entry from a `Dictionary` (by `Key`) AND retrieve its `Value` **in the same step**?

For example, I'm calling

```
Dictionary.Remove(Key);
```

but I also want it to return the Value at the same time. The function only returns a `bool`.

I know I can do something like

```
Value = Dictionary[Key];
Dictionary.Remove(Key);
```

but it seems like this will search the dictionary twice (once to get the value, and another time to remove it from the dictionary). How can I (if possible) do both WITHOUT searching the dictionary twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785091/is-there-any-implementation-to-remove-by-key-and-get-the-value-at-the-same-time This thread has an accepted answer

Comment: If it is also performance related, you could thake a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869452/a-faster-replacement-to-the-dictionarytkey-tvalue and see if that clears anything up

Comment: @Kenneth: So, I guess it cannot be done with the "built-in" dictionary type in .NET?

Comment: @Mash: Assuming your `Key` caches or trivial calculates the Hash code, the performance cost of double lookup is trivial. Most dictionaries have O(1) lookup and removal.

Comment: afaik, no, but since it's such an obvious and a legit requirement, I figured someone must have asked it before. I guess the only possible way would be to implement your own dictionary. Not to be critical, but I doubt that it will be faster :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with .NET Core 2.0, we have:

> public bool Remove (TKey key, out TValue value);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netcore-2.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Remove__0__1__

Note this API hasn't been included [in .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netstandard-2.0) and [.NET Framework 4.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netframework-4.7).

Comment: Nice! Thank you for providing the reference.

Comment: It *is*, however, included in [.NET Standard 2.1 (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netstandard-2.1)

Comment: Nowadays, this should be accepted answer

Comment: @Yennefer agreed, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Because they both have the desired missing method I tried Microsoft's [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) and C5 from University of Copenhagen http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/ and I can tell with, at least with my use case it was super slow (I mean 5x - 10x slower) compared to Dictionary. 
I think C5 is sorting both keys and values all the time and Concurrent Dictionary is "too worried" about the calling thread.. I am not here to discuss why those two incarnations of Dictionary are slow.
My algorithm was seeking and replacing some entries whereas the first keys would be removed and new keys would be added (some sort of Queue)...
The only think left to do was to modify original .Net mscorelib's Dictionary. I downloaded the source code from Microsoft and included the [Dictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) class in my source code. To compile I also need to drag along just the [HashHelpers](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,de3ba4873d4ad06a) class and [ThrowHelper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/throwhelper.cs,73669ffe9b1ee4f4,references) class. All that was left was to comment out some lines (e.g. `[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<,>))]` and some resource fetching). Obviously I had to add the missing method to the copied class. Also do not try to compile Microsoft Source code you will be doing that for hours, I was lucky enough to get it going.

```
   public bool Remove(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        }

        if (buckets != null)
        {
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
            int bucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
            int last = -1;
            for (int i = buckets[bucket]; i >= 0; last = i, i = entries[i].next)
            {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key))
                {
                    if (last < 0)
                    {
                        buckets[bucket] = entries[i].next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entries[last].next = entries[i].next;
                    }
                    entries[i].hashCode = -1;
                    entries[i].next = freeList;
                    entries[i].key = default(TKey);
                    value = entries[i].value;
                    entries[i].value = default(TValue);
                    freeList = i;
                    freeCount++;
                    version++;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }
```

Lastly I modified the namespace to `System.Collection.Generic.My`
In my algorithm I only had two lines where I was getting the value than remove it in the next line.. replaced that with the *new* method and obtained a steady performance gain of 7%-10%.
Hope it helps this use case and any other cases where re-implementing Dictionary from scratch is just not what one should do.

Comment: So basically, modify Microsoft's library. This question has been out for a while and this answer appears to be as good as it gets, so I'll accept this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not what the OP has asked for, I could not help myself but post a corrected extension method:

```
public static bool Remove<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> self, TKey key, out TValue target)
{
    self.TryGetValue(key, out target);
    return self.Remove(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `concurrentDictionary` has a `TryRemove` method that attempts to remove and return the value that has the specified key from the `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.`
It returns the default value of the `TValue` type if key does not exist.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an Extension method:

```
public static string GetValueAndRemove<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<int, string> dict, int key)
{
    string val = dict[key];
    dict.Remove(key);
    return val;    
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> a = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    a.Add(1, "sdfg");
    a.Add(2, "sdsdfgadfhfg");
    string value = a.GetValueAndRemove<int, string>(1);
}
```

Comment: Since Remove is safe, I would suggest checking if the key exists first, but good idea anyhow :)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I should have been more clear when I said "in the same step." What I really mean is not search the dictionary twice. The `string val = dict[key]` will search the dictionary once and the `dict.Remove(key)` will search it again.

Comment: @Mash Dictionary is really fast, so performance-wise it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: @Silvermind I agree, it really wasn't an issue of performance, just a thought that occurred to me while I was coding something

Comment: If you look under the hood of the Dictionary in the University of Copenehagen's Generic Collection Library, you'll probably find the same implementation. Unfortunately you cant do this in one step.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I haven't looked into their code but I'm not willing to go through all the trouble to use their Dictionary over Microsoft's. Upvote for providing something where I can do it in one call.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the class to add that functionality:

```
public class PoppableDictionary<T, V> : Dictionary<T, V>
{
    public V Pop(T key)
    {
        V value = this[key];
        this.Remove(key);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still needs two lookups. The OP requested a method to eliminate the double lookup

Comment: You are right. I answered based on @Guvante's comment which states that access operations to dictionaries are o(1) so there's no significant performance penalty in accessing the dictionary twice.

Comment: @Toto Yes, I was mainly looking for avoiding the double lookup in the dictionary but thank you for providing something where I can at least do it in one call (upvote).